# Data type 0x23 is a deprecated large object, or LOB, but is marked as output parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, adodb, lob, varcharmax

I'm trying to receive a `varchar(max)` output `param` from an `stored procedure` but I'm getting the error above , i.e `Data type 0x23 is a deprecated large object, or LOB, but is marked as output parameter` when I execute the `SP` in `vb.net`

I have tried using `SQLNCLI11` connection string, no luck
I have tried setting `Datatypecompatibility=80`, no luck

thanks in advance.

here are my codes:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     Button1.Click
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim db As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim PromoRejectDesc As String = ""

    db.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;UID=user;Pwd=password;Database=POSData;Server=localhost;DataCompatibility=80;MARS Connection=True"

    db.Open()

    cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = db
    cmd.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "DBO.proc_PromoRejectingFactors"

    prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@CustID", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput)
    prm.Value = 1050009326
    cmd.Parameters.Append(prm)
    prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@BranchID", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput)
    prm.Value = 101
    cmd.Parameters.Append(prm)
    prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@FulfillmentChannel", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput)
    prm.Value = 1
    cmd.Parameters.Append(prm)
    prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@Tender", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput)
    prm.Value = 0
    cmd.Parameters.Append(prm)

    prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@CreditCard", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput)
    prm.Value = -1
    cmd.Parameters.Append(prm)

    prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@ExcludePromo", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 1000)
    prm.Value = ""
    cmd.Parameters.Append(prm)

    prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@PromoRejectDesc", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamOutput, 9999)
    cmd.Parameters.Append(prm)

    Rs = cmd.Execute
    If Rs.State = 1 Then
        PromoRejectDesc = prm.Value
        MsgBox(PromoRejectDesc)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have solved my problem.

First, I have set CursorLocation to adUseClient

```
db.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;UID=user;Pwd=password;Database=POSData;Server=localhost;DataCompatibility=80;MARS Connection=True"
db.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
db.Open()
```

Then, for the output parameter datatype, I have used adBStr

```
prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@PromoRejectDesc", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adBSTR, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamOutput, 999999)
    cmd.Parameters.Append(prm)
```

Everything works fine after that!

By the way, I'm receiving 18,255 (length) characters.

Comment: I only needed the `adBSTR` to get mine to work. Thanks!